# Toggling CSS to change background

Tags: javascript, css, toggleclass

In a tic tac toe game, when a game is won, I want the winning line's background to go red.

I have taken the winning line box id's into an array as such-

```
if (cell1.innerText == symbol && cell2.innerText == symbol) {

if (cell3.innerText == symbol) {
  winningLine=[cell1.id,cell2.id,cell3.id]; //contains the id's of winning line
  winFlag = true;
}
......
```

Then I add the css when a win is confirmed using this function-

```
 function addOrRemoveCSS(line){

  var i=0;
  while(i<3){

    var cell=$(line[i]); // This is my main doubt. Can I do this??
    cell.toggleClass("winningCSS");
    i++;

  }
 }
```

Is there something wrong that Im doing here?? Because there is no change in the background.

Comment: It will definitely work fine, here's a codepen example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOxMXm

Comment: What does the console say? ...make sure to include the `#` with your ID

Comment: @leoOrion Just like mentioned you should include the ID

Comment: @AkinjideBankole ...tag ;)

Comment: Yeah I added the # and it started working. Thanks. In your codepen eg. It was not added and yet it worked!!?? Also going a little off topic here... How did you use $() without importing jquery into codepen ??

Comment: Actually jQuery is included, click the settings button at the top, navigate to the Javascript pane, you'll see quick-add dropdown. Lots of Javascript framework there

Comment: @leoOrion If you're still confused about why it worked in the codepen example: AkinjideBankole included the "#" right in the string array he passed (`addOrRemoveCSS(["#h","#d","#e"])`)

Comment: Thanks... I did not notice that. Thanks evryone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `#` with your ID:

```
function addOrRemoveCSS(line){

  var i=0;
  while(i<3){

    var cell=$("#"+line[i]);
    cell.toggleClass("winningCSS");
    i++;

  }
 }
```

The jQ selector needs to know it's an ID you're looking for. You're just passing the strings without the ID selector `#`

Comment: Thanks... Worked like a charm